# Magento 2 : How to set product name and product price in custom email template?

Tags: magento2

I want to ask how can we set values of product name and product price in my custom email template.

Comment: Do you have product id where you want to email..?

Comment: Yes i have product id in my observer. I m getting custor name shipping address but i dont no how to set product price and name in email templates

Answer (score 0):

```
$product_id = 'get id';
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product') //getting product model
$_product = $model->load($product_id); //getting product object for particular product id
$name =   $_product->getName(); //product name
$price =  $_product->getPrice(); //product's regular Price
```

This the way to get name and price. Now use $name and $price like this.

```
echo $name;
echo $price;
```

Comment: I think it's for magento 1 and i am asking for magento 2

Comment: but brother i am asking how can i set values in custom email template ?

Comment: where are u making template if you have product id as i asked before you can use that id and get name n price by this code

Comment: I am getting price and name but if i dont no how to print array values in email template. I am using like this {{var productName}}. where productName is an array. How can i print all the values in email template